# Update data frame using tidy functions

Tags: r, dplyr

Here is example data frame:

```
qseqid  sseqid  pident
NP_040593.1 J02459.1    100
NP_040593.1 JQ086376.1  100
NP_040593.1 JQ182735.1  100
NP_040594.1 NC_049953.1 99.306
NP_040594.1 OM418625.1  99.306
NP_040594.1 NC_049954.1 98.611
NP_040594.1 CP025712.1  98.611
NP_040594.1 OL657226.1  98.611
```

How to update dataframe to have distinct (using `dplyr::distinct` probably)  `pident==100`, but keep all other pident values (including duplicates) the same?

So, to something like that:

```
qseqid  sseqid  pident
NP_040593.1 J02459.1    100
NP_040594.1 NC_049953.1 99.306
NP_040594.1 OM418625.1  99.306
NP_040594.1 NC_049954.1 98.611
NP_040594.1 CP025712.1  98.611
NP_040594.1 OL657226.1  98.611
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may use `filter` - create a logical condition with `==` on 100 value and change the TRUE to FALSE where that are `duplicated`  or (`|`) to select all other other values (`!=`)

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  filter(pident == 100 & !duplicated(pident)| pident != 100)
```

-output

```
      qseqid      sseqid  pident
1 NP_040593.1    J02459.1 100.000
2 NP_040594.1 NC_049953.1  99.306
3 NP_040594.1  OM418625.1  99.306
4 NP_040594.1 NC_049954.1  98.611
5 NP_040594.1  CP025712.1  98.611
6 NP_040594.1  OL657226.1  98.611
```

---

This may also be done with `base R`

```
subset(df1, pident == 100 & !duplicated(pident) | pident != 100)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(qseqid = c("NP_040593.1", "NP_040593.1", "NP_040593.1", 
"NP_040594.1", "NP_040594.1", "NP_040594.1", "NP_040594.1", "NP_040594.1"
), sseqid = c("J02459.1", "JQ086376.1", "JQ182735.1", "NC_049953.1", 
"OM418625.1", "NC_049954.1", "CP025712.1", "OL657226.1"), pident = c(100, 
100, 100, 99.306, 99.306, 98.611, 98.611, 98.611)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: Perfect! Waiting to accept the solution.